# Can we delete the 'books' tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

It does not get more [meta](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) than this tag. It does not add anything new to the question.

There are currently 19 questions tagged [books](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/books) and in nine cases it is also tagged [reference-request](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request), which is also a meta tag with (almost *?*) the same scope. The other cases are either just plainly missing the tag or are off-topic anyway (primarily opinion based/ t[o]<sub>n</sub> broad, n∈{2 .. ∞}). There are two legit uses of [erratum](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/erratum), according to our [scope extension](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1661/4945), that just don't need this tag.

I would propose retagging to ref-req where absolutely necessary (to not bump old questions) and silent death of [books](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/books).

There has already been a discussion about allowing book questions in the first place: [Should we allow books questions?](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/118/4945)

---

Have a few examples:

- (Borderline) Off-topic Reference requests

  - [A good book for learning paper and thin-layer chromatography](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/25038/4945)
  - [Biochem Book age and suggestions](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/25144/4945)
  - https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/24830/4945 (That whole question may be murdered in my opinion.)
  - [What are some popular science books in chemistry?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/24812/4945)
  - [Organic chemistry textbook for self-learning?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/14703/4945)
  - [Books for a very advanced 3rd grader (elementary school)](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/4747/4945) (needs retagging, otherwise [untagged](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged))
- It would not hurt the question not to have it

  - [Pointless comparison in Clayden et al., Organic Chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/7424/4945)
- Erratum (already tagged)

  - [Is this textbook bonding picture of hybridization in ethene wrong?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/10906/4945)
  - [How many Ga atoms are connected to one As atom in solid state Gallium arsenide](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/9317/4945)

Comment: Sounds good to me. Let it go. Btw, I just gave the 3rd question a first stab in the back :-)

Comment: As far as I remember three stabs from three different people are necessary or a superstab from a diamond person. I cannot stab yet. But the bot should clean the orphaned question soon.

Comment: Hearty +1 to this.

Comment: I grabbed the two erratum questions, as I think those were a slam dunk for removing the tag.

Comment: I really think reference-requests offer a lot of bang for the buck, so to speak. They require relatively short answers, and they put the asker on route to learn a great deal. However, requests for 'good books', etc. are subjective questions, and this site doesn't deal with those kinds of questions. Accordingly, perhaps we ought to require reference requests to specify what they want in a reference: what qualifies a book as a 'good book on x' according to the asker. That way, the question can actually be objectively-satisfactorily answered.